# Adding "1;" to the bottom of a cgi script that uses Perl?

Tags: perl, scripting, cgi

I know that perl scripts (.pl) need the "1;" at the end of them for use, etc....

But if you have a cgi script (.cgi) which uses Perl, does the "1;" need to be at the bottom of it as well?  I know this is a very basic question, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: The `1;` just needs to be there for Perl modules, not scripts.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, I know it's a really basic question, but I copied a pl script over to a cgi script and wanted to make sure I didn't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Modules (files executed using `require` or `use`) and scripts executed using `do` require a true value. Scripts executed by `perl` itself (e.g. CGI scripts) do not (though there's no harm in doing so).

Comment: `do` returns the last value; no reason it couldn't be false.  though it does return undef for a compile error and distinguishing that is a good idea.

Comment: +1 but `do FILE` simply returns the value of the last statement. There is no requirement for it being a *true* value. It is only `require` that dies with `did not return a true value` if the contents of the module evaluate to false

Comment: @Borodin, You can't detect whether an error occurred or not unless you return true for `do`. So while `do` itself doesn't require it, using `do` does. (`do('file.pl') or die $@ || $!;`)